# R. Moses al-Ashkar's Response to Sefer ha-Emunot

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, rambam, rishonim, machlokes

Where can I find the Maharam al-Ashkar's response to Shem Tov ibn Shem Tov's Sefer ha-Emunot (Hassagot Al Mah She-Katab R. Shem-Tov Neged ha-RaMbaM)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See שו"ת מהר"ם אלשקר סימן קיז on Hebrewbooks.org [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1168&pgnum=299).

Answer (score 0):

I found it [here on Daat](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/pilosof/sefer1-2.htm) but would also like to see it in an original publication, e.g. on HebrewBooks.